# NetGear WNDA3100v2 802.11 not instaling

Tags: wireless, drivers

so far I managed to get the headers downloaded, and the system updated, I have ndiswrapper installed.  But when I get to the checkinstall I get this:

```
*****************************************
**** Debian package creation selected ***
*****************************************

This package will be built according to these values: 

0 -  Maintainer: [ icon@tron ]
1 -  Summary: [ ndiswrapper ]
2 -  Name:    [ ndiswrapper ]
3 -  Version: [ 1.59 ]
4 -  Release: [ 1 ]
5 -  License: [ GPL ]
6 -  Group:   [ checkinstall ]
7 -  Architecture: [ amd64 ]
8 -  Source location: [ ndiswrapper-1.59 ]
9 -  Alternate source location: [  ]
10 - Requires: [  ]
11 - Provides: [ ndiswrapper ]
12 - Conflicts: [  ]
13 - Replaces: [  ]

Enter a number to change any of them or press ENTER to continue: 

Installing with make install...

========================= Installation results ===========================
make: Warning: File `Makefile' has modification time 3.8e+08 s in the future
make -C driver install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/icon/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.59/driver'
make[1]: Warning: File `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-33-generic/.config' has modification time 4.2e+08 s in the future
make modules
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/icon/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.59/driver'
make[2]: Warning: File `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-33-generic/.config' has modification time 4.2e+08 s in the future
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-33-generic M=/home/icon/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.59/driver
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-33-generic'
make[3]: Warning: File `scripts/Makefile.extrawarn' has modification time 4e+08 s in the future
make[4]: Warning: File `scripts/Makefile.lib' has modification time 4e+08 s in the future
MKEXPORT /home/icon/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.59/driver/crt_exports.h
MKEXPORT /home/icon/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.59/driver/hal_exports.h
MKEXPORT /home/icon/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.59/driver/ndis_exports.h
MKEXPORT /home/icon/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.59/driver/ntoskernel_exports.h
MKEXPORT /home/icon/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.59/driver/ntoskernel_io_exports.h
MKEXPORT /home/icon/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.59/driver/rtl_exports.h
MKEXPORT /home/icon/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.59/driver/usb_exports.h
MKSTUBS /home/icon/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.59/driver/win2lin_stubs.h
CC [M]  /home/icon/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.59/driver/crt.o
/home/icon/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.59/driver/crt.c: In function ‘_win_srand’:
/home/icon/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.59/driver/crt.c:470:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘net_srandom’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
net_srandom(seed);
^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[4]: *** [/home/icon/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.59/driver/crt.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [_module_/home/icon/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.59/driver] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-33-generic'
make[2]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/icon/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.59/driver'
make[1]: *** [ndiswrapper.ko] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/icon/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.59/driver'
make: *** [install] Error 2

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Restoring overwritten files from backup... FAILED!

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.

icon@tron:~/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.59$
```

any help at all would be appreciated

Comment: Why not do: `sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-utils-1.9`?

Comment: I typed that in too much of a hurry.  No internet access on the ubntu machine, i have a windows machine that I can connect with though.  I have followed every guide I could find on this site and others, so far none have worked.  It has been 2 weeks now, my brain is fried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you download these packages to your desktop. Be sure to get the packages appropriate to your architecture; either 32- or 64-bit.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/ndiswrapper-utils-1.9

http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/ndiswrapper-common

Once they are on your desktop, install with:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i ndis*.deb
```

Comment: That worked.  Ndiswrapper is working now and I got the driver installed.  Now is there another program I need to control it?

Comment: Network Manager, which is installed by default, should control your wireless connection. If my answer was helpful, please accept it.

Comment: Network manager says it is installed, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.  Which seems to be leaving me unable to connect to anything.

Comment: I think you have a new question. We answered 'how to install ndiswrapper' and now you need to ask where to find the missing nm-applet. I believe there are several questions with answers on that subject so search carefully. If you are unable to find a satisfactory answer, please post a new question and we'll be very happy to help you.